# Div goes off screen on Firefox when lower width viewport / Not on chrome

Tags: html, css, viewport

I have a div element on my page that is relatively positioned to a parent div

Element in question's CSS (it have both classes) :

```
.message {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: #4A4A4A;
    text-transform: initial;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.message-three {
    left: -105px;
    top: -250px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    /* margin-right: auto; */
}
```

It's parent's (both classes also) :

```
.spot {
    z-index: 4; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
    border-radius: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.spot-three {
    top: -1px;
    left: 9px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

When I redimension my viewport (width) with navigator's dev tool :

- on Chrome, the right border of the screen "pushes" my element so it keeps the 20px margin-right (and below a certain viewport, all the elements of the page shrink)
- On Firefox elements keep the same size regardless of the viewport but my element is going off the screen of the right

I want to prevent my element from going off-screen on Firefox but I don't know-how

EDIT:
Html

```
<div id="data-bar" class="row data-project">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="position: relative; z-index:4;">
        <div class="spot spot-three">
            <div class="message message-three">
                <h2 class="message-title">{{'info.thirdMessage.title'|trans}}</h2>
                <p class="message-text">{{'info.thirdMessage.message'|trans|nl2br}}</p>
                <div class="message-bottom-line">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" onclick="messageSlide(1)"><i class="far fa-circle dot-empty"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" onclick="messageSlide(2)"><i class="far fa-circle dot-empty"></i></a>
                        <i class="fas fa-circle dot-full"></i>
                    </div>
                    <button class="menu-item primary-button" onclick="hideMessage()">{{'info.close.btn'|trans}}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

data-bar CSS :

```
#data-bar {
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 2;
                width: calc(100% - 40px);
                bottom: 20px;
                border-top-left-radius: 3px;
                border-top-right-radius: 3px;
                background-color: #505050; 
                margin-left: 20px;
                justify-content: stretch;
                border : solid;
                border-top-width: 1px;
                border-left-width: 1px;
                border-right-width: 1px;
                border-bottom-width: 0px;
                border-color: #3E3E3E;
                color: white;
            }
```

col-sm-2 CSS :

```
.col-sm-2 {
                padding: 20px;
                max-width: 20%;
                flex: auto;
            }
```

Comment: Please include your HTML.

Comment: done (parent of data-bar is <body>)

Comment: Well, u've told your browser to keep that .message at `width: 300px`, so FF trying hard to fulfill that. Set a `max-width: calc( 100vw - someValueInPixels )` or add a media query to change the width or left position.

Comment: Yeah, I need to keep it 300px. But I'll try to move the .message box with media-qeries. Thanks